# linux command line: du --- how to make it show only total for each directories

Tags: linux, command-line

I am doing it by (with coreutils_8.5-1ubuntu6_amd64):

```
du -sch `find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type d`
```

I am looking for a simple way (shorter cmd) to find **size of subdirectories**. Thank you.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

This works with coreutils 5.97:

`du -cksh *`

Comment: No way, it doesn't. `*` is being expanded by the shell, so `du` gets a list to be processed anyways.

Answer (score 125):

On my version of du (from coreutils 8.14) this works:

```
du -h -d 1
```

-h is for human readable sizes.

Comment: Sad to say, it not work for me, coreutils_8.5-1ubuntu6_amd64, thank you.

Comment: This works fine for me, although I’ve set the -d limit to 0 to only show dir’s in the current directory.

Comment: `du -h -d 1 /` to get the root directories size

Comment: @Marcel `-d 0` gives you a total for the current dir, not subdirectories, as OP asked for.
@Andrew_1510 if `-d` is not working, try `--max-depth=` instead. More info at: https://linux.die.net/man/1/du

Comment: for short you can use; du . -hd 1

Answer (score 26):

The following did the job for me:

`du -hs */`

Without the trailing slash the output was not restricted to directories.

Comment: nice! simple and It did the work

Answer (score 15):

This command is your answer:

`du -sh *`

Answer (score 6):

actually you can try :

```
du -kh | cut -f1
```

Answer (score 1):

All these answers didn't work for me, I think some parameters depend on the environment.

So I did this:

```
du -csh /home/pi/walala/* | grep total | sed 's/ *\stotal* *\(.*\)/\1/'
```

OR for bytes

```
du -csb /home/pi/walala/* | grep total | sed 's/ *\stotal* *\(.*\)/\1/'
```

Comment: This is a great one

Answer (score 0):

create an alias:

```
alias subs="du -sch `find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type d`"
```

and I thing 'subs' is much shorter.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have the following treeview:

```bash
/fodler/202206
```

in which  we would have the list of folders

```bash
|-- 20220601
|-- 20220602
|-- 20220603
|-- 20220604
|-- 20220605
`-- 20220606
```

If I understand your question, you would like to have shown, only the total for each folders called `20220601...20220606`

Enhancing the response of [Albert Veli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1315776/albert-veli) above.
you enter the folder which contains all the sub-folders you would like to have the size.

In this use case, you enter:

```bash
cd /folder/202206
```

and retrieve the size of each of the sub-folder only

```bash
du -h -d 0 *
```

The option `-h` (human readable) `-d` is the depth to display and then to show only the size of subfolder, you choose `-d 0`

Another option would be to change the `-d 0`with a `-s` (which means summarize) and it would give the same result

the output would be like as below

```bash
677M    20220601
693M    20220602
781M    20220603
630M    20220604
616M    20220605
713M    20220606
```

PS: if you need to have anyway a grand total, you could replace the `-h`with `hc` but this is not the question.